# How can I utilise a vector in a method call that requires an array?

Tags: c++, directx, directx-10

For example, this method:

```
memcpy(pVoid, MyStructArray, sizeof(MyStructArray));
```

This used to be fine because I was calling this method once on instantiation where the array was sa pre-defined size. However it became necessary to change the information in the 'array' dynamically, so I'm using a vector instead. Is the information in a vector guaranteed to be contiguous?

could I do something like

```
 memcpy(pVoid, &MyStructVector, sizeof(*MyStructVector) * MyStrucVector.size());
```

Comment: I think *MyStructVector would not work, how can I get the size of one element? or can I literally just do sizeof(MyStructVector)?

Comment: The size of one element is `sizeof MyStructVector[0]`; and a pointer to the first element is `&MyStructVector[0]`. Also, don't forget to check that the vector isn't empty first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data in a `std::vector` is contiguous.  But you can't copy it like you are doing.  You can, however, do this:

```
memcpy(pVoid, &MyStructVector[0], sizeof(MyStructVector[0]) * MyStrucVector.size());
```

Comment: For C++11, `MyStructVector.data()` can be used rather than `&MyStructVector[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes std::vector is contiguous.

you should use `&MyStructVector[0]` where you expect a standard C-style array pointer